# Why did Tandy see what she saw?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, runaways-2017, cloak-and-dagger

When Tandy touches Alex's hand shortly before they return from the Dark Dimension, she sees his hopes, which appear to consist of having the powers of all the other runaways. This makes her reluctant about bringing him back, and causes the others to doubt him briefly. This  vision pays off when we see an evil version of him from the future come back to seek revenge.

Except, does it? As far as we are told, Alex did not pursue his revenge until someone, whom he presumably believed to be Nico, put a bomb in his office and tried to kill him. It seems that at the point at which Tandy had her vision, Alex was at most somewhat resentful that no one had tried to rescue him sooner, but certainly not plotting to betray his friends and try to take their powers, as evidenced by the fact that he took no action against them until the aforementioned event. Indeed, we see that the Alex from a somewhat closer future works against the evil future Alex with his friends, and seems absolutely disgusted with the idea that he would turn into someone so callous. In short, everything suggests that he did not harbour sinister ambitions. This is made slightly more peculiar by the fact that evil future Alex did not appear to have been making any effort to acquire these powers, although in fairness what someone hopes and what they know they can realistically accomplish are not necessarily equivalent.

So why did Tandy see this vision of Alex? Did he really *hope* to have all their powers, but was unwilling to act on that desire due to his morality? *Did* she see the hopes of some evil alternate version of him, as he suggested, a version that in this case would be the evil Alex from the future? Was he actually plotting to betray his friends at that point?